# Waiting for region servers count to settle;currently checked in 0

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

when I start HBase, from the monitor web, the task of master-startup always show the status described as this title.
And also hbase shell command cannot work.
There were no error in master or region-server log;
I have searched and tried so much ,such as change 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1 nothing to help.

### Hosts

```
 - 127.0.0.1  localhost
 - 127.0.0.1  ubuntu-fzz
 - 192.168.248.128   master
 - 192.168.248.129   slave1
 - 192.168.248.130   slave2
```

### HBase-site.xml

```
<property><name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name><value>master,slave1,slave2</value></property>
<property><name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name><value>2181</value></property>
<property><name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name><value>/home/fzz/zookeeper-3.4.9/zdata</value></property>
<property><name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name><value>true</value></property>
<property><name>hbase.rootdir</name><value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value></property>
```

### zoo.cfg

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/home/fzz/zookeeper-3.4.9/zdata
clientPort=2181
server.1=master:2888:3888
server.2=slave1:2888:3888
server.3=slave2:2888:3888
```

first try hbase, appreciate all your help,thanks

Answer (score 0):

i got it.
it was the host exception.
ubuntu-* is my machine name;
after i refer three machine name to the right ip (192...),
it worked! forgive my poor english skill